# Why isn't the turtle moving?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I was coding a turtle game where when the snake goes near the "apple", it goes to a random cord and we repeat. I tried to add a go to function in python but it is not moving for some reason. I added a check to see if the if statement is happening and it is, but after the check, nothing runs. What is the problem with my code?

```
import turtle as t


import random

wn=t.Screen()


t.shape("turtle")
t.pu()

apple=t.Turtle()

apple.pu()

apple.shape("circle")
apple.color("red")

def forw():
  t.forward(10)
def back():
  t.backward(10)


wn.onkey(forw,"Up")
wn.onkey(back,"Down")
wn.onkey(lambda: t.left(45),"Left")
wn.onkey(lambda: t.right(45),"Right")
wn.listen()

if t.distance(apple)<=15 or t.distance(apple)>=-15:
  print("check1")
  apple.goto(random.randint(-50,50),random.randint(-50,50))
```

Comment: Your program as written will just terminate.  Add wn.mainloop() after wn.listen()

Comment: You are performing the distance check *exactly once*, as your program is starting up - the user has had no chance to actually move the snake yet.  You need to perform the check after each move, in other words in both `forw()` and `back()`.  (Ideally the check would be in a separate function called in both of those places, so you don't have to repeat the code.)

Comment: Also, comparing the distance to -15 is unneeded - the distance will always be a non-negative number.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all your help! I figured out the code and got it to work!

Comment: Feel free to post a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to help others with the same problem as you.